# Why am I getting a "no module named cx_Freeze" error after installing cx_freeze?

Tags: python, windows, cx-freeze

I am trying to compile a python program and I am using python 3.2.
So I downloaded **cx_freeze** and installed it. When I try to run the **setup.py** in cmd it says:

```
"importerror: no module named cx_freeze"
```

I have removed **cx_freeze** and tried to re-install it, this time however, in the **"select the location where cx_freeze should be installed"** part of the installation I selected python from registry (which is all I did before) and also selected **"python from another location"** (and choose my C:\python32\ directory). Then I got this error:

```
"There is a problum with this windows installation package. a program required for this install to complete could not be run."
```

note: in my **setup.py** file is the following:

```
from cx_freeze import *

Setup(
    name = "",
    version ="0.1",
    description ="",
    executables = [Executable("")] ,
)
```

Comment: You're getting your capital letters mixed up: try with `cx_Freeze` and `setup()`. I don't know if that's the problem, though, because I thought loading modules on Windows was case insensitive.

Comment: I just tried to load cx_Freeze on Windows 7 64-bit using `cx_freeze` however the only thing that worked was with the capital `cx_Freeze`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally found the solution to this problem! Been trying for two days and a programmer friend helped me (I'm not a programmer myself).

So, when you type in "python setup.py build" to cmd, what it tries to do is look for python.exe in the folder you are in, and if it doesn't find it there then looks to system paths (which you can access with the command "echo %PATH%").

So it looks there, it finds python and runs it - but python doesn't have cx_Freeze. Why? Because the python in the system path is an older version you have!! For me it was 2.6.5, despite me using 3.3. And this older version naturally didn't have cx_Freeze in it because I installed it to 3.3. This also explains why trying "import cx_Freeze" in IDLE works without problems.

To see which version of python cmd is calling, type only "python" in cmd and it will show you.

Ok, so the quick solution is to simply add the full absolute path leading to desired python.exe. For python 3.3 it's:

```
c:\python33\python setup.py build
```

The long-term solution is to add python 3.3 to your system paths. I haven't done it myself, but this should be the info on how to do it http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

It's a late answer, but I hope this at least helps someone else. Enjoy your cx_Freeze

Comment: If you are using python3 perhaps "pip3" and "python3" is in your path? If so "pip3 install cx_freeze" would have installed it into your python3 environment and "python3 setup.py build" would have worked?

Comment: This was the case on Arch too... `python2` instead of just `python`

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue with python version 3.8.

I found when updating `cx_freeze` using a compiler, it converted to a pip install, and somehow removed the site-packages path from the `%PATH%` environment variable for the anaconda environment I was operating in.

From  marcelotduarte at [github](https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/issues/682#issuecomment-662906376),

> If you have a C compiler, you can test the development version:
> `pip install -U git+https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze.git@develop`

I uninstalled the module using `pip uninstall cx_freeze`, and then reinstalled using anaconda, `conda install cx_freeze`. This corrected the problem and aligned the path variables properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Mac and use Python3, install cx_Freeze like this:
`python3 -m pip install --upgrade cx_Freeze`
then run `python3 setup.py build`