# Error in cx_freeze Build

Tags: python, build, bundle, cx-freeze, package-managers

I am using cx_freeze to bundle my app. I have 2 questions.

1) I am using OSX Mountain Lion - the /build/exe.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7 that I have - will it contain executables for Windows, Linux as well - and if so, where in the list can I find it? My original script is cpu.py. The dir contains a lot of ".so" files and 1 "cpu" file.

2) When I try "cpu" from the list above, I get this output. 'psutil' is a Python module required for the script - cpu.py.

```
Desktop/build/exe.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/cpu ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in    <module>
exec code in m.__dict__
File "cpu.py", line 6, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
import psutil._psosx as _psplatform
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 14, in <module>
import _psutil_osx
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/_psutil_osx.py", line 7, in <module>
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/_psutil_osx.py", line 4, in __bootstrap__
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 945, in resource_filename
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1626, in get_resource_filename
NotImplementedError: resource_filename() only supported for .egg, not .zip
logout
```

Comment: Re 1) No, you need to run cx_Freeze on all platforms independently to get respective executables. On Mac you will only get an executable for Mac.

Comment: I thought as much but wanted to be sure. Thanks :)

Comment: If you have two questions, it's best to ask them separately on SO, that it's clear when they're answered. As to (2), `psutil` uses `pkg_resources`, which doesn't work with frozen modules in a zip file. You'll have to patch it to make it behave.

Comment: Thanks. I used bbfreeze to make it now. Let's see if it works, else I'll get to the patch. (Will keep in mind the SO advice :)  )